# Figures "not responding" when generated in a while loop in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, figure

Is it possible to have multiple figures generated and shown within a loop? I would like to display each figure, so that I can inspect it, before moving on to the the next one. To make this question clearer, I have written a little example of what I would like to do. At the moment, the figures are displayed as "not responding", so I can't see whats in them. I have tried using plt.waitforbuttonpress and plt.ion, but this doesn't seem to be working.

I am using the spyder editor, but it would great if the solution could work in other editors as well (like idle).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pi = 3.14
figureTime = 1.0

x  = np.arange(0,2*pi,0.1)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

plt.ion()

for i in xrange(1,11,1):

  plt.close('all')    

  # Figure 1
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(x,y1*i)
  plt.show()
  plt.draw()
  plt.waitforbuttonpress(timeout=figureTime)
  raw_input("Press Enter to continue")
  plt.close()


  # Figure 2
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(x,y2*i)
  plt.show()
  plt.draw()
  plt.waitforbuttonpress(timeout=figureTime)
  raw_input("Press Enter to continue")
  plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

ok solved it. The following code works for spyder and idle. All you have to do is call plt.ion() outside the loop, and plt.waitforbuttonpress() when ever you want to pause the figure! Easy!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

pi = 3.14

x  = np.arange(0,2*pi,0.1)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

plt.ion()

for i in xrange(1,11,1):

  plt.close('all')    

  # Figure 1
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(x,y1*i)
  plt.show()
  plt.waitforbuttonpress()

  # Figure 2
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(x,y2*i)
  plt.show()
  plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```